# Is it possible to convert an Android device into a midi input device for Logic Pro

Tags: midi, logic-pro

I tried [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pash.piano) and used WireShark to see what's being sent, it seems to be sending midi commands over udp, although none is recognized by the network driver in the Audio MIDI Setup.

Also tried [ipMIDI](http://www.nerds.de/en/ipmidi_osx.html) and [MolCp3](http://www.musiclab.com/products/midioverlan/info.html) but could't get to the udp settings, it seems those use a custom protocol or some wrapper on top of the midi commands.

Answer (score 1):

The USB connector of almost all recent Android devices can be switched into "host mode", making it to follow the same communication standard as if it would be USB port on PC.

In most of devices, Android operating system also has the necessary programmer support. However on some devices this is intentionally disabled. There are [USB checkers](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=check%20USB%20otg&hl=en) on Play Store that can verify if your device supports the needed protocols before dealing with music-specific stuff.

Hence, in general, yes, in theory it should be possible. It makes sense to try apps that claim to be capable of this, it is not so that cannot be done in principle. However this is a complex programming task and I expect to find many broken/buggy/incomplete implementations in Play Store. Try multiple apps, and if something "almost works", try to talk with developers of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find something like what I was looking for, so I made a [small app](https://github.com/rraallvv/IP2MIDI) to capture the midi commands coming from upd and play the corresponding midi notes in a core midi virtual source.